# How to remove left recursion in he following?

Tags: left-recursion

Here is the productions.

```
A-> Aa| b|c;
```

Now shall i do

```
A->bA' 
A'-> aA' | e (empty transition)
A->c
```

Will it be the right answer? That is either 'b' or 'c' can be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say, there has to be 'b' or 'c' at the beginning, so more like this:

```
A -> bA' | cA' 
A'-> aA' | e
```

Comment: could you help me with this too. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9250363/first-and-follow-sets